# c++ pass pointer to vector for "multiple" class

Tags: c++

Hy guys, i need pass a point of vector to constructor of one class, and in contructor pass this point to other constructor,

```
/*======================== Class Dados/Data ========================*/
class Dados
{
    string nome;
    int valor;
public:
    Dados(string n, int v) : nome(n), valor(v){};
    //~dados();

    string GetNome()const{return nome;}
    int GetValor()const{return valor;}

    void SetValor(int x){valor = x;}



    string GetAsString() const {
        ostringstream oss;
        oss << nome <<": "<< valor;
        return oss.str();
    }
};


/*======================== Class FileReader ========================*/
class FileReader{

    vector<Dados> dados;

public:
    bool ReadFile(string file) {
        dados.empty();
        string fnome, ftemp;
        int fvalor;
        ifstream fich(file);
        string linha;


        if (fich.is_open())                 
        {

            while (fich.peek() != EOF){

                getline(fich, linha);

                istringstream iss(linha);

                //cout << ".";
                iss >> fnome;               
                iss >> ftemp;
                iss >> fvalor;
                dados.push_back(Dados(fnome,fvalor));
            }


            fich.close();

            return 0;

        }
        else{ 
            cout << "Ficheiro \""<< file <<"\" nao encontrado!";
            return 1;
        }
    }


    string GetAsString() 
    {
        ostringstream oss;
        vector<Dados>::const_iterator it;
        it = dados.begin();
        while (it != dados.end()){
            oss << it->GetAsString() << endl;
            it++;
        }
        return oss.str();
    }


    int FindOnVector(string const fi)
    {
        int val = -1; //-1 se for erro
        vector<Dados>::const_iterator it;

        it = dados.begin();
        while (it != dados.end()){

            if(fi == it->GetNome()){
                val = it->GetValor();
            }
            it++;
        }

        return val;
    }


    void Save(){

        vector<Dados>::const_iterator it;

        it = dados.begin();
        while (it != dados.end()){
        cout << it->GetAsString() << endl;
        it++;
        }
    }

};
```

On main i have,

```
void main(int argc,char** argv){
    FileReader fr;


    if( fr.ReadFile(argv[1])==0){
        cout <<endl<< fr.GetAsString();
    }else {
        cout << "[ ERRO ]" << endl;
    }
    jogo g(&fr);
    cout << "\n\n-------------Test2--------------------" << endl;
    fr.Save();
}
```

two other class:

```
class jogo{


public:
    jogo(FileReader *A){

        teste t(&A);


    };


};

class teste{

public:
    teste(FileReader *C){

        vector<Dados>::const_iterator it;
        it = C.begin();
        while (it != C.end()){
            cout << it->GetAsString() << endl;
            it++;
        }
    };


};
```

In class Jogo i try pass the point of FileReader to the test class, but is not possible. 
what am I doing wrong?

sorry this is not the necessary specific.

ERROR: In class Teste
when I try to use the pointer of C me this error:

```
1   IntelliSense: expression must have class type   e:\is\Documents\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Source.cpp  141
```

best.

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you by chance having problems with to many (unneeded) indirections?

Comment: sorry i forgot: 
In class teste on C.

 1 IntelliSense: expression must have class type e:\is\Documents\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Source.cpp 141

Comment: @Góis can you distill this down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Góis there is a link in my comment to the help which explains EXACTLY what MCVE stands for

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see it: You most probably get an error on calling `teste`s constructor because you're missing a Forward reference to that class. Use .h files for the two classes or declare teste before jogo.

Comment: I have in .hand is declared bedford jogo.

Comment: sorry i forget:
n class Teste when I try to use the pointer of C me this error:

1   IntelliSense: expression must have class type   e:\is\Documents\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Source.cpp  141

Comment: `teste` ctor is taking a `FileReader *` argument. You're giving it a `FileReader**` now. (Wasn't this different just before...?)